# Weighted Distance with Focal Statistics / Raster Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, inverse-distance-weighted

I have a raster image of a road network with pixel values corresponding to vehicule frequency.

[image]

What I would like is to calculate a weighted distance raster with the frequency as weight within a maximum distance. I don't seem to grasp the concept of how to reference neighbouring cell values.

How do I refine and apply a formula like the following or better in the raster calculator AND / OR how can I make Focal Statistics work with a weighting formula?

```
newraster(x,y) = 
     for all i in range(-maxdist, maxdist):
        for all j(-maxdist to maxdist):
            oldraster(x-i,y-j)*(1-distance/maxdistance)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a bit of work outside of ArcGIS to create a custom kernel that you will use with focal statistics (NbrWeight). The kernel will be store in a text file.

```
The inKernelFile is an ASCII text file that defines the shape of the neighborhood and the weight of each cell in that neighborhood. A value of 0 for a cell position indicates that the cell is not a member of the neighborhood, and a number at a corresponding cell's position indicates that the cell value be included as a member of the neighborhood. The nonzero value will also serve as the weight to multiply the corresponding cell value
```

So, in your case, here is an example of kernel for max dist = 2 (yes, I am lazy).

```
3 3 
0.293 0.5 0.293 
0.5 1 0.5 
0.293 0.5 0.293
```

When distance = 2 (or more) the weigth = 0
When distance = 1, the weight = 1-1/2 = 0.5
when distance = sqrt(2) (on the diagonal), the weight = 1-1/sqrt(2) ~= 0.293

if you add a print in your script, you'll see all the values for a given maximum  distance (in pixel).

Comment: i ended up creating kernels through python which turned out to be the best solution. thanks!